# Firebase Remote Config and Firebase Analytics's scalibility

Tags: firebase, scalability

Do you know what is the scalability of Firebase Remote Config and Firebase Analytics services? Is there a limitation on how many users can fetch their configurations at the same time, or logging events at the same time? And what is the expected behavior on mobile clients if Firebase servers are overloaded?

Answer (score 2):

*firebaser here*

There are no documented limits for these services. While there is probably some theoretical limit to how much they can handle, we haven't seen it in practice yet.

Firebase Analytics will temporarily hold on to its analytics until it can report them.

Firebase Remote Config will continue to use the previous/default configuration until it is reconnected.